# Easiest/most affordable way to boost voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, parallel

I'm running a setup with two parallel D-cell LiSOCl2 batteries (3.6V, pulse currents up to 3000mA), to power up a small microcontroller. However, as I deploy my devices in very cold environments (down to -35 to -40C in the winter) the voltage of these batteries drops down all the way to about 2.5V or so, and they can no longer support the microcontroller (which has minimum of 3.3V, and maximum of 4.2V).

What's the easiest way of ensuring that the supplied voltage stays within the operating range of my microcontroller? My batteries right now connect with a JST-connector straight into the microcontroller. Preferably, I want to change as little as possible to my setup. Any guidance?

Battery: http://gebc-energy.com/en-US/Product-60.html

[Better battery spec...](http://www.greenergy-battery.com/Specs/li-SOCl2/ER34615M.pdf)

Comment: Batteries have far less accessible energy available, too, when cold. If possible, I'd recommend keeping the battery between −5˚C and +20˚C. Self-heat, if necessary. Insulate them well. It may be that the cost of the energy to do that will be paid by having access to the additional energy that a heated battery can provide. How long will these devices be in their environments between visits?

Comment: Lithium-thionyl chloride(Li-SOCl ) Battery Packs have higher ESR and drop V more than std LiPo.  Early models had low ESR caps in shunt.   That temp range does not state loss in  V or Ah , it just operates.  Boost regulators transform to lower load impedance to make things possibly worse.

Comment: Once placed in the environment, the devices are expected to remain there for at least 1-2 years. If a major issue arises it's possible to visit it, but that should be kept to a minimum due to their remote locations.

Comment: boost regulators exist in the 90~98% efficiency range depending on ratings and design

Comment: "in very cold environments (down to -35 to -40C in the winter) the voltage of these batteries drops down all the way to about 2.5V or so" - at what current? "the microcontroller... has minimum of 3.3V" - which microcontroller is that?

Comment: It would be nice to know more about the application. Average and peak current draw, expected run time before recharging, etc.

Comment: I doubt self-heating the battery would be even remotely efficient.

Comment: Avg. current draw is about 500uA, with peaks up to 800mA. Batteries are non-rechargeable, and the expected run time at room temperature is expected to be 2 to 3 years (will be significantly lower at colder temperatures)

Comment: You want to change as little as possible but dont describe your current setup. Pulse current is in amperes, not amoete-hours. Is that a battery pack or two separate batteries? That voltage requirement sounds like a modem - what kind of modem?Is it a custom PCB or a hobby project out of ready-made components? Is your main MCU and the high-current part the same IC/module or are they separate? All this stuff needs consideration. And if you answer them - please edit those answers into your question. Not everyone reads comments.

Answer (score 5):

Before you do anything.. make sure the rest of the circuitry operates within spec at -40C. If it doesn't, getting more life out of the battery is moot.

Further, you need to work out what the power output of that battery is at -40C. If it is less than your required power level plus conversion efficiency, you will not be able to boost it.

If, and only if, those are within tolerances, there are numerous buck-boost regulators available online you can use. Some will be termed as "Joule thief" circuits.

Your other alternative is to make the device self-heating. That of course involves sacrificing some controlled battery current to keep the device warm enough and some clever thermal insulation to keep the cold parts warm using minimal current while still allowing you to cool the hot parts.

Comment: The rest of the components can operate up until -40, although I don't expect temperatures to go lower than -30 (-35 to -40 really is a very extreme scenario). The batteries can support the power usage (which is a continuous 150uA, with pulses up to 500mA) easily I believe.

Comment: @Vitesze is that battery rating at -40C though.. Your link is non specific.

Comment: Sorry, here's a more detailed link: http://www.greenergy-battery.com/Specs/li-SOCl2/ER34615M.pdf. At -40C,  it should still be able to deliver 1000mA at 2.4V (it doesn't list higher currents in the graphs, but 1A is more than what I need anyway). So in an extreme scenario, I should be able to convert the 2.4V into a steady 3.6V

Comment: @Vitesze it will be close... boosted back to 3.6V your .8A peak current will be closer to 1.2 to 1.3A at the battery. Of course it depends how long "peak" is and how well whatever  bulk capacitance you have covers that.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to inquire with the battery producer regarding this, to understand exactly what the supplied voltage and maximum pulse currents are it can provide at these temperatures. That should probably give me the answer whether a booster can work

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not in the circuit but in the thermal conditions you are submitting the hardware.

There are solutions, simple and cheap to solve the problem, without altering the design, there are cases ready, to submit circuits to vacuum which is the best thermal insulation.

Otherwise, for these conditions you would have to redo the project, because after the long-term exposure you will encounter other problems, not just the batteries.

Comment: It depends how long it will stay in the cold. If temperature stay between -20 and -35C more than one week, even the best insulation won't be of any help.

Comment: Both convection and conduction can not occur in a vacuum, as they need a material means for them to occur.

Comment: Yes. In theory.

Comment: They're placed outside, in some of the colder climates (e.g. northern Alberta) so we're talking here about strongly fluctuating temperatures, but in the winter it can peak at -25 to -30C.

Comment: @Vitesze: Peak or trough (or nadir) at -25 to -30°C? Trough, I imagine.

Comment: @rafa radiation does occur in a vacuum, though. Besides, you will not have a vacuum but a low pressure (possibly inert and low thermal transmissivity) gas that will allow a little convection. Also, unless the board can float completely disconnected from the wall of the container (not only by antigravity, but also by avoiding any connection with the outside world - like cables to sensors, antennae and the like), you will experience appreciable conduction.

Answer (score 1):

If this cold condition is occuring most of the time and not just a few days per year, I would use 5V batteries and a step down converter or even a linear converter, set to 3.8V (+-0.2V). When freezing temperatures lower the voltage of the battery to less than 4V, then the step down converter can be turned off and the power used directly. Linear converters are very efficient for very small voltage drops, and nearly zero loss when there is none. But are much less efficient when the voltage drop is more significant. The two options should be analysed carefully. The linear solution is much more compact and simple in regard to component count, therefore cheaper too. If, to the contrary, the weather is warm most of the time, then use a 3.6V battery with a boost converter in case of sudden cold weather. In both cases i would design a system to turn off the converter when not needed, if this function doesn't exist already within the converter itself.

Comment: They will be place outside, so it's very dependent on the weather. But in the winter, I expected an average temperature of -15C, with peaks up to -30C. The reason I use this 3.6V LiSOCl2 battery, is because it has extremely little self-discharge (about 1%/year). If there is a 5V battery with a similar self-discharge, I'd be very interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation could perhaps be a good scenario for supercapacitor (or EDLC, or Electric Double Layer Capacitor) use, since the high ESR of most batteries at your low temperatures and high currents wastes a significant amount of your battery energy, especially at end of charge-life -- you want to sip the current from your batteries where the ESR is much lower and charge up some supercaps (or regular caps) slowly, and when they are charged, then spend the energy you've stored up in the supercap(s) to run your one amp pulse need.

So, a [1 Farad 2.7 volt supercap costs 1 USD on digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/electric-double-layer-capacitors-edlc-supercapacitors/61?FV=1c0011%2C1c0002%2C1c0003%2C1f140000%2Cmu1F%7C2049%7C0%2Cffe0003d&quantity=&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&k=supercapacitor&pageSize=50&pkeyword=supercapacitor), and you didn't say how long your 1 Amp pulse was, so we don't know how much energy you really need all at once.  But your batteries will last much longer if you use a switched converter to charge your capacitors or supercapacitors just before your high-energy pulse need.

Although supercaps work fairly well at low temps, and will deliver the high pulse you need, they are also leaky, so I suggest using the smallest ones that will work for your application (with margin), and then charging them up just before use.  (Would it make sense to pump the remaining supercap energy back into your storage batteries?)  Keep in mind also that they will seem more "leaky" when you first charge them, but as the charges migrate deeper into the electrodes, that should go away to some extent (or so I read).

A few years ago, I bought about 6 supercaps they call "D-Cells" because they're about the size of a standard D cell flashlight battery, and I started my car (1994 Toyota Corolla) with the string of them [350-Farad 2.7v](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/maxwell-technologies-inc/BCAP0350-E270-T11/1182-1016-ND/3079280), and they cost less than $10 USD each at quantities over 100 -- I just had to see it for myself.  I am not recommending such large capacitances for your application, for even though they would definitely handle your pulse need (and then some), their leakage would probably waste too much energy for your application.

One resource I have found helpful for thinking about these things (though he didn't cover supercaps, I think) is the special series by Jack Ganssle written in 2014 on ultra low power design titled ["Hardware and Firmware Issues in Using Ultra-Low Power MCUs"](http://www.ganssle.com/reports/ultra-low-power-design.html).  There's a lot more on the site sprinkled about as well at his ["Random Rants"](http://www.ganssle.com/randomrants.htm), like his review of [a (pricey, but interesting) tool for converting low currents to show on an oscilloscope](http://www.ganssle.com/rants/amperecurrentsensor.html), since you're working on a remote application and have to optimize your energy usage.